# mod_spamhaus whitelist example to allow a range of ips

Tags: apache, spam

How would an example whitelist look like, that would whitelist a
range of all IPs from `123.123.0.0 - 123.123.255.255` ?

I have the whitelistfile in

```
/etc/spamhaus.wl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a good half an hour searching the web and found absolutely no documentation regarding your question, neither in English nor in Italian ([`mod_spamhause`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-spamhaus/) author [Luca Ercoli](http://www.lucaercoli.it/en/mod_spamhaus.html) is Italian). We're not entirely out of luck, though. [The `mod_spamhause` code was published on-line](http://mod-spamhaus.sourcearchive.com/) and we can have a look at how filters are handled in [this unit](http://mod-spamhaus.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.7/mod__spamhaus_8c_source.html). The part of the code relevant to your question is (*in C++*):

```
if ( (strchr(lista[count],'/') == NULL )){
  if ( strcmp(lista[count],r->connection->remote_ip) == 0  ) return 1;
}
else {
  sscanf(lista[count], "%[^/]/%u", ippi, &bitmask);
  sscanf(ippi, "%lu.%lu.%lu.%lu", &a, &b, &c, &d);
  first = (a << 24) + (b << 16) + (c << 8) + d;
  mask = (0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - bitmask));
  last = first + (~mask);
  first = htonl(first);
  last = htonl(last);
  in.s_addr = first;
  sscanf(inet_ntoa(in), "%d.%d.%d.%d", &a_min, &b_min, &c_min, &d_min);
  in.s_addr = last;
  sscanf(inet_ntoa(in), "%d.%d.%d.%d", &a_max, &b_max, &c_max, &d_max);
  sscanf(r->connection->remote_ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &a_daverificare, &b_daverificare, &c_daverificare, &d_daverificare);
  if (
     ((d_daverificare <=  d_max) && (d_daverificare >=  d_min)) &&
     ((c_daverificare <=  c_max) && (c_daverificare >=  c_min)) &&
     ((b_daverificare <=  b_max) && (b_daverificare >=  b_min)) &&
     ((a_daverificare <=  a_max) && (a_daverificare >=  a_min))
  ) return 1;
}
```

It's quite straight-forward, but if you don't read C++ then let's just sum it up that it will accept both individual IPs as well as [`CIDR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation) ranges, formatted same as Apache does.

To answer your question then, according to this code, you can add a [`CIDR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation) range `123.123.0.0/16` (that covers IPs *123.123.0.0 - 123.123.255.255*) as a single line in your `/etc/spamhaus.wl` like so:

```
123.123.0.0/16
```

The published code would handle [`CIDR notation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation), however we have no way of knowing this code is actually in use with your [`mod_spamhaus`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-spamhaus/) build. If it doesn't work for you then I'd suggest you search for other builds, or compile your own version using [SourceArchive.com published code](http://mod-spamhaus.sourcearchive.com/).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After looking up the module, there is very little to no documentation on how it expects the whitelist to be. I would gather to guess that it will take CIDR based values or individual IPs.