# Is apache mod_spamhaus still being maintained?

Tags: apache, mod-security

I only found this: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-spamhaus/files/?source=navbar
and that is from 2008

Is there any newer apache mod that is up-to-date?

Someone has experience with it? Maybe [mod_defensible](http://www.howtoforge.com/block-spammers-hackers-with-mod_defensible-on-apache2-debian-etch)?

Answer (score 5):

I've been in the hosting industry for years now and I've never even heard of these 2 ever being brought up in the industry by other professionals. Honestly, I would consider them "dead". Not too mention that the idea of blocking at Apache's level is not the best. You can better block IPs at the firewall and prevent them from hitting the server all together.

Comment: depending on your use case scenario, these modules can be very useful. most illicit crawlers (which scan for holes in web applications) almost never probe anything else of the server. moreover, the code required to block something using a DNSBL service is incredibly small and requires little afterthought. considering that mod_defensible is in the latest ubuntu repository, I wouldent consider them "dead".

Answer (score 2):

I've found a [x86 64-bit version 0.7-6 Mandriva Linux build from February 2012](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/mandriva/devel/cooker/x86_64/media/contrib/release/apache-mod_spamhaus-0.7-6.x86_64.html), so I guess it's still being used and [Luca Ercoli's](http://www.lucaercoli.it/en/mod_spamhaus.html) [original `mod_spamhause` code](http://mod-spamhaus.sourcearchive.com/) still receives some attention every now and then, albeit in two year steps it seems.

Latest distributable package that I could find is [version 0.7-1 on Debian](http://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/mod-spamhaus). Only looking at the date the code was last changed alone doesn't tell you plenty on how much it's still used or how well it functions, though. I've run through the code ([as explained in another question you asked](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/30275/20074)) and I see no reason why it would need much changing anyway, so it might simply work and there's no need to change it. If it checks with [Spamhaus `DNSBL`](http://www.spamhaus.org/dbl/) fast enough, and enables you to add custom *BL* and *WL* local rules, then *'it does what it say on the box'*.

[Spamhaus project](http://www.spamhaus.org/) is alive and kicking (literally) as strong as it ever was, so I really see no reason why you wouldn't give [`mod_spamhause`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-spamhaus/) a try.

Answer (score 2):

mod_spamhaus for Apache 2.2 is alive and well at http://www.miim.com/software/linux/modspamhaus.html.  This version is based on Luca Ercoli's earlier versions which are no longer being maintained.

It may work under Apache 2.4, but the author says that this hasn't been tested.

This is the version that I use.  You can also get other protection modules at this site.

The site uses extensive protection including geolocation, mod_spamhaus, mod_torcheck and mod_honeypot.  So don't be surprised if you're located outside the U.S. and cannot get access.